# USB-to-LAN plugged in and out suddenly not working on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, lan

I have the ICY-Box ethernet to usb 3.0 adapter. It worked perfectly. I opened my computer to add another SSD and had to disconnect the cables. After i connected them again the adapter is not working anymore. It is not even recognized from Windows. The LAN-lights are off and i can't find any entries for it in the device manager...
How is that even possible? I mean i just reconnected the damn cable. Any ideas?

Comment: After complete reset of Windows 10 I ruled out the chance of any 3rd party software problem. Now its back on default Windows settings and still nothing happening ...

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that the USB cable somehow got loose. Unplug the cable entirely (the usb part) wait 5 seconds, and reinsert. Windows should detect the plug again and make it work. If this does not work, insert the USB into a different port, to force windows to reinstall the drivers.

Comment: Well, by "disconnected" and "reconnected" I obviously meant that I already unplugged the cables entirely. I also tried every USB port, including the USB 2 ones. Windows does not do anything, no plug-recognising, no errors, no feedback of any kind.

Comment: To rule out a problem on your computer, does this specific USB plug work on another computer? If not, then somehow the plug might be damaged.